# Read and Write png file without change file size in C (libpng)

Tags: image-processing, png, libpng, deflate

I want to read the **png** file, see Image Data and write again without any change in file size. Based on **libpng** documents,the png is lossless and use **deflate** and **lz77** for compression. There is an example project in libpng which has claimed to read and write image without loss, it's correct in pixel values, but change the structure of file (such as number of IDATs, optional chunks and etc) png file size.

My explicit question:
How to extract encode parameters (such as deflate params or lz77 params) from compressed stream (Zstream in libpng) and use this parameters to encode raw image to create image file same as input file without any change?

This is my code. I try to hold params in *info_ptr* to write image,but not work. How to do it?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
inname = argv[1];
outname = argv[2];

png_structrp read_ptr = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);
png_infop info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(read_ptr);



if (!info_ptr)
{
    png_destroy_read_struct(&read_ptr, (png_infopp)NULL, (png_infopp)NULL);
}

png_FILE_p imageFile, imageFile2, imageFileW;
    imageFile=fopen(inname, "rb");  imageFileW = fopen(outname, "wb"); imageFile2 = fopen(inname, "rb");

int fileSize=fsize(imageFile2);
unsigned char* bufImWrite = malloc(sizeof(char)*fileSize);
fread(bufImWrite, 1, fileSize, imageFile2);

png_init_io(read_ptr, imageFile);

png_read_info(read_ptr, info_ptr);


png_uint_32 height;
height = info_ptr->height;


png_bytep * row_pointers;

row_pointers = (png_bytep*)malloc(sizeof(png_bytep) * height);
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    row_pointers[y] = (png_byte*)malloc(png_get_rowbytes(read_ptr, info_ptr));


png_read_image(read_ptr, row_pointers);


png_read_end(read_ptr, info_ptr);


png_structp png_ptr = png_create_write_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);;
png_init_io(png_ptr, imageFileW);
png_write_info(png_ptr, info_ptr);
//png_set_compression_level(png_ptr, 9);
//png_set_compression_window_bits(png_ptr, 15);
//png_set_compression_strategy(png_ptr, 3);
//png_set_compression_mem_level(png_ptr, 8);

png_write_image(png_ptr, row_pointers);
png_write_end(png_ptr, info_ptr);


}
```

Comment: This is a strange request. If you don't want the file changed, just copy it. If you want to change the image content, it is likely that achieving exactly the same compression rate is impossible. If you want to change some tags, change them in-place.

Comment: This question is correct @YvesDaoust (down vote?). He needs to get raw image data, and compress this data again to generate same file. It's different from copy (in compression science). What's your solution for this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to Glenn's correct response, even if you somehow had the parameters used for compression, the compression may have been done by code that is no longer available, or by code that is proprietary and not available to you. In either case there is no way to replicate the exact compressed data. *Just keep the original compressed data if you're not going to mess with the image.*

Answer (score 7):

A PNG file does not contain a record of the exact deflate/zlib parameters used for compression, so what you want is not really possible.  If you need to preserve the original encoding, you should keep a copy of your original PNG file rather than destructively reading it.

If you want to change ancillary PNG chunks without changing the image data, use some application such as [tweakpng](http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/) to copy the IHDR, PLTE, IDAT, and IEND chunks from your original PNG file into the new file.

If, as the comments suggest, you want to add a watermark without changing the compressed datastream, that's simply impossible because the image data is different.  If you really need a removable watermark, use some editable format such as SVG to keep the watermark separate, or a format such as APNG where the watermark can be stored in a separate part.  The disadvantage of that is that anyone could remove the watermark from their copy.

Comment: Thanks @Glenn Randers-Pehrson,  based on your note,I can’t decode and encode png file and generate identical file. I’m working on image watermarking, and my method limited to the file size. In other word, I want to embbed watermark bits in the compressed data stream of png, also consider the changes of **adler** and **crc** after manipulation of data. Can you tell me **where is the best position of compressed zlib stream for manipulate** that save the data structure and image quality?

Comment: If you are adding a watermark, then you are changing the image data, and it is absolutely impossible to keep the same compressed datastream, because it is a different image being compressed.

Comment: I suppose it would be possible to use the APNG format to add a watermark as a second frame to be overlaid on the first, but that's probably out-of-scope for this question.  I suggest that you simply give up on the idea and live with the re-compressed image data.

Comment: Thanks @Glenn Randers-Pehrson again for your attention,I know watermarked image is not same as input image, but generate identical image is first step. Because if i can't generate identical image, i can't extract watermark in other side. So my idea is change compressed data and generate image nearly similar to input. I do it in jpeg by change DCT coefficient in compressed data and looking for a way to do it in PNG(Change deflate result). Anyway thanks to you.